# Is there any way to define a compile-time (expansion-time) macro variable in Racket or any other Scheme?

Tags: macros, scheme, racket, define-syntax

To give a simple example:

```
(define-macro-variable _iota 0) ; define-macro-variable does not really exist

(define-syntax (iota stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    ((iota)
     (let ((i _iota))
       (set! _iota (+ i 1))
       #`#,i))))
```

Such that given:

```
(define zero (iota))
(define one-two-three (list (iota) (iota) (iota)))
(define (four) (iota))
```

the following should all evaluate to `#t`:

```
(equal? zero 0)
(equal? one-two-three '(1 2 3)) ; possibly in a different order
(equal? (four) 4)
(equal? (four) 4)
(equal? (four) 4)
```

Is there any real racket feature that does what `define-macro-variable` is supposed to do in the example above?

EDIT:

I found a work-around:

```
(define-syntaxes (macro-names ...)
  (let (macro-vars-and-vals ...)
    (values macro-bodies-that-nead-the-macro-vars ...)))
```

but I would prefer a solution that does not require all the macros that use the macro variables to be in one expression.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want [`define-for-syntax`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define.html?q=define-for-syntax#%28form._%28%28lib._racket/private/base..rkt%29._define-for-syntax%29%29) (in Racket).

```
(define-for-syntax _iota 0)

(define-syntax (iota stx)
  (syntax-case stx ()
    ((iota)
     (let ((i _iota))
       (set! _iota (+ i 1))
       #`#,i))))

(define zero (iota))
(define one-two-three (list (iota) (iota) (iota)))
(define (four) (iota))

(equal? zero 0)
(equal? one-two-three '(1 2 3))
(equal? (four) 4)
(equal? (four) 4)
(equal? (four) 4)
```

produces all true.